# How to percentile Pie Chart data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using PieChart from recharts. I want to display my data as a percentile. I try to convert the data sting but then the data start doesn't work. How can I do it?

```
const data01 = [
        { name: "Dönen Varlıklar", value: asset_1 },
        { name: "Duran Varlıklar", value: asset_3 },
      ];
var asset_1 = (assets.titles[0].values[0].value)*100
var asset_3 = (assets.titles[1].values[0].value)*100
...

<PieChart width={500} height={300}>
    <Pie
        data={data01}
        cx={250}
        cy={130}
        innerRadius={60}
        outerRadius={80}
        fill="#8884d8"
        paddingAngle={5}
        cornerRadius={20}
        dataKey="value"                                                                                            
   > 
        data01.map((entry, index) => (
        <Cell key={`cell-${index}`} fill={COLORS[index % COLORS.length]} />
   </Pie>
   <Legend/>
   <Tooltip />
```

[image: My chart]

Comment: There is not enough information here to give an accurate answer.  Please edit your question to include more context.  Start by showing us what "data string" and "data start" are and how you get them.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `label` property of the `Pie` to a function and return the new label string from the function. The function param has a `percent` property that is the percentage of the pie that the current slice represents. e.g. 0.27 for 27%

[Pie docs (not much detail tho)](https://recharts.org/en-US/api/Pie#label)

```js
const data01 = [
        { name: "Apples", value: 34 },
        { name: "Pears", value: 9 },
        { name: "Bananas", value: 45 },
      ];

const renderCustomizedLabel = ({ percent }) => {
  if (!percent) return null; // Don't show zeros
  return `${(percent * 100).toFixed(0)}%`;
};

<PieChart width={500} height={300}>
    <Pie
        data={data01}
        cx={250}
        cy={130}
        innerRadius={60}
        outerRadius={80}
        fill="#8884d8"
        paddingAngle={5}
        cornerRadius={20}
        dataKey="value"
        nameKey="name"
        label={renderCustomizedLabel} 
   > 
        data01.map((entry, index) => (
        <Cell key={`cell-${index}`} fill={COLORS[index % COLORS.length]} />
   </Pie>
   <Legend/>
   <Tooltip />
</PieChart>
```